# Display from array only once

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im using the following code. It goes through a DB and pulls out the question and the related answers.

However it displays the question each time it prints an answer.

How can I make it so the question is only printed once and then the answers are printed.

```
$qna = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT q.QText, a.id, a.AText FROM question q INNER JOIN answer a ON q.id = a.Question_ID WHERE q.id=1")  or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($qna)) {

echo '<td>'.$data2['QText'].'</td>';

echo '

<table class="layout display responsive-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Answer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tr>
    <td>'.$data2['id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$data['AText'].'</td>
    <td>'.$data['Group_ID'].'</td>
    </table>

';

  }
```

Comment: Just remove LOOP (WHILE) and make it $data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($qna)

Comment: @MulhamAryan  that does not work

Answer (score 1):

Select an ID from question table aswell like:

```
SELECT q.QText, q.id AS QId, a.id, a.AText FROM ...
```

And then you can print out the question only once using condition:

```
$lastQuestionID = 0;
while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($qna)) {

if($data2['QId'] != $lastQuestionID)
    echo '<td>'.$data2['QText'].'</td>';

$lastQuestionID = $data2['QId'];

// printing answer here

}
```

Comment: Notice that the condition should only apply on QText echoing, be sure you didn't wrap printing answer aswell.

Comment: my bad , i had a group by bit (experimenting). However it wont print out the AText bit

Comment: Iv checked the field is called AText in the DB . It shoudlnt matter that its a varchar

Comment: Hey I found a problem . for me it prints the first question , then the second and then the answers to the first so its always a question behind